# Use a non-monospaced font with Gnome Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have a font I'd like to use in the Gnome Terminal that the OS doesn't recognize as monospaced (I assure you it is). Is there any way to set Gnome Terminal's font to something that isn't monospaced? The font in question is Menlo patched for Powerline from https://gist.github.com/qrush/1595572.

I'm on GNOME Terminal 3.4.1.1.

Comment: What version of Gnome Terminal are you using? I've just tested this in version 2.16.0 on RHEL5, and it has no trouble letting me choose a proportional font. (Granted, it renders the font thus chosen as though it were monospaced, but it doesn't refuse to list proportional fonts or allow them to be selected.)

Comment: @AaronMiller: I should have mentioned that. I'm on 3.4.1.1.